# Insert data from textarea in PHP to MySQL database (also skip duplicate)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to bulk insert some data in PHP from a textarea form, and then prevent duplications from already existing data. I tried to code something but right now it just inserts everything that I insert in the textarea in same "value" in the column. But I want each line from the textarea separated in each and own column.

Here is what I have so far, and this works but it inserts the whole row:

```
<?php
include '../includes/config.php';
if (isset($_POST["data"])) {

    $_POST["ban"] = $value;
    $line_data = explode("\n", $_POST["data"]);
    foreach ($line_data as $key => $value) {
        $checkQuery  = "SELECT ip FROM blacklist WHERE ip='" . $_POST["ip"] . "'";
        $checkResult = mysqli_query($con, $checkQuery);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($checkResult) != 0){
            // do nothing 
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO blacklist (ip) VALUES ('{$value}')";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="bulk.php" method="post"> 
<textarea type="text" name="data" placeholder="IP address"></textarea><br/>
<button type="submit" name="ban">Ban</button>
</form>
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong and is there good way to handle this? If so, how?

**Edit:** It inserts into it's own column now, but it still duplicates. Like it's still possible insert same thing many times even if data exists in database.

Comment: that depends on how you split the ip-addresses in your text area. by newline? by semicolon? Anyway, an `explode()` would help. Then iterate through the result, and insert. And checkout [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: @Jeff Splitting them by a newline. I forgot to mention that

Comment: Updated my question, it still duplicates but it works inserting now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Comment: `$checkresult` doesn't say if it returns zero or more rows. It only checks if the select was successfull (to be precice: it returns a restult-set that would evaluate to loose == '1' which is kinda true). You need to check for [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding mysqli_num_rows. I updated question again, still inserting duplicates. I most likely did this wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can function `explode` for splitting values in field `ip` into lines. Save each line with ip address as separate record in your db table `blacklist`